# Creating dynamic objects with | separator python

Tags: python, django

What I want is to solve is something like this

```
names = ['Aleister', 'Matovu']
args = (Q(name__contains=name[0])|Q(name__contains=name[1]))
queryset.complex_filter(args)
```

What the problem is I have a names as a dynamic object and its length is not fixed. What I am thinking would work is if I looped though the names and created a dynamic `args` object but I am not sure what kind of object that is. I am not sure how exactly to do that, so I am stuck.

If you can help around that, that will be really cool or if you can give me an alternative way to go about the same scenario that would be awesome.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django : How to Query model where name contains any word in python list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088173/django-how-to-query-model-where-name-contains-any-word-in-python-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import operator
names = [...]
query = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(name__icontains=name) for name in names])
results = queryset.complex_filter(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what `Q` is in this case, but maybe

```
import operator
qq = [Q(name__contains=i) for i in name)]
args = reduce(operator.or_, qq)
```

might help. But as this is the same as [Timmy wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13838553/296974), don't upvote me, but him.

If not, see at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7088173/296974).

Comment: ~name__contains==i for i in name~
name__contains is not defined, please add some bit context, thank you

Comment: Forget it. As I don't know this stuff, I thought it might be a comparison, but is a keyword argument. As said, resort to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7088173/296974), or look at [Timmy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13838553/296974). Updated this answer, but I probably will delete it soon...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty satisfying solution. If it is ever of any help to anyone

http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.com/2009/06/adding-q-objects-in-django.html

```
q = Q(content__icontains=term_list[0]) | Q(title__icontains=term_list[0])
for term in term_list[1:]:
    q.add((Q(content__icontains=term) | Q(title__icontains=term)), q.connector)

stories = stories.filter(q)
```