# matching substring to list of string in django

Tags: python, django

I have a list of strings (say `s = ['1995','1996','1997']`). I need to find all rows in my database, where some column's first four characters match any item in that list (For example `1995-01-01` or `1996-05-04`).

Found `__in`, but it finds exact matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import operator
years = ['1995','1996','1997', ...]
query = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(year__startswith=year) for year in years])
results = queryset.filter(query)
```

This would give you SQL similar to `WHERE year LIKE '1995%' OR year LIKE '1996%' ...;` which [mightn't perform well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause) given your dataset. You might get better performance writing the SQL manually using [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

Strangely, I just answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13838553/396300) previously with almost the exact same code!